# Load css and js files from the array then call function in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a js json array like

```
var plugs={
                "material":[
                    "css":["plugins/Material/css/roboto.min.css",
                            "plugins/Material/css/material-fullpalette.css",
                            "plugins/Material/css/ripples.min.css"], 
                    "js":["plugins/Material/js/ripples.min.js","plugins/Material/js/material.min.js"],


                    "fire":"materialInit"
                ]
            }
```

I am using this to load external plugin files. So what my need is that the js and css files in the array should be loaded first. Then after completing this action a function `"fire":"materialInit"` should be  called.

1. Load css and js files from the array then
2. call function in the array

Thanks in advance,

Comment: i was doing it with ajax loading through php like

foreach($pluginsB as $v){
  $fileCss=$plugins[$v][css];
  $fileJs=$plugins[$v][js];
  if ((is_array($fileJs)) or ($fileJs instanceof Traversable)){
   foreach($fileJs as $v2){ ?>loadFile("<?=$v2?>");<?php  }
   }else{?>loadFile("<?=$fileJs?>");<?php }
  if ((is_array($fileCss)) or ($fileCss instanceof Traversable)){
   foreach($fileCss as $v2){ ?>loadCss("<?=$v2?>");<?php  }
   }else{?>loadCss("<?=$fileCss?>");<?php }
  }

But it makes some problems that's y I am luking for this.I didnt got any reference to wait until load a an array of files

Comment: @swaraj sorry i couldnt show it cleanly through the comment

Comment: You can edit your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution..., Hope this may help someone else

```
var promises=[];
function loadCss(file){
$("<link/>", {
       rel: "stylesheet",
       type: "text/css",
       href: file
    }).appendTo("head");
}

$.each(plugs, function (index, value) {
    if(value['js'])
    var jsD=value['js'];
    if(value['css'])
    var csD=value['css'];
    var arrayName = index;
    promises[arrayName] = new Array();
    if(csD)
    if( typeof csD === 'string' ) {
        loadCss(csD);   
        }else{
        $.each(csD, function (index2, value2) { loadCss(value2); });
        }
    if(jsD)
    if( typeof jsD === 'string' ) {
        var file=jsD;
        var request=$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: file,
              dataType: "script",
              async: false,
              cache: true,
              success:function(){console.log(file);},
              fail:function(){console.log("fail loading "+file);}
            });
        promises[index].push( request  );   
        }else{
        $.each(jsD, function (index3, value3) { 
             var file=value3;
             var request=$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: file,
              dataType: "script",
              async: false,
              cache: true,
              success:function(){console.log(file);},
              fail:function(){console.log("fail loading "+file);}
            });

          });
        }

    promises[index].push( request  );
        $.when.apply(null, promises[index]).done(function(){
            //console.log(plugs[index]['fire']);
            if (typeof plugs[index]['fire'] !== 'undefined' && $.trim(plugs[index]['fire'])!='')
                window[plugs[index]['fire']](); 
            });

    });//plugs loading end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot work on JSONs inside php , you need to perform a json_decode($jsonString) , and then access it via your foreach loop.

e.g :

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$php_equivalent = json_decode($json);
?>
```

you cannot load files with php , all you can do is modify and/or create elements

so you can create a js funtion for that  like this-

```
 function loadCSS(href)
 {
var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = href
link.media = 'all';
head.appendChild(link);
}
```

and call that function using php like this -

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javscript'>";
echo "load($csshref)";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

same you can do to load js files

Comment: I already know that and was not trying to do that. Here what I shown is the json array output after processing my php array.